# Send DTMF Digit with dialplan

Tags: asterisk, telephony, freepbx

I have the following dialplan:

```
    exten => 224,1,NoOp(IN CALL : ${CALLERID(num)} => ${EXTEN})
    exten => 224,n,Dial(${PJSIP_DIAL_CONTACTS(97,97)})
    ;exten => 224,n,Wait(3)
    exten => 224,n,SendDTMF(*11234*,200)
    exten => 224,n,Wait(3)
    exten => 224,n,SendDTMF(#*)
    exten => 224,n,Hangup()
```

When I call the extension 97 and it is connected, it doesnt seem to go next in line SendDTMF. What am I doing wrong?

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

For who is looking for something like this without SendDTMF application, you can send DTMF with D option:

```
exten => n, Dial (SIP/97,60,D(1234))
```

If the DTMF passed are getted on the other side incomplete, use w option to delay 500 milliseconds.

Here I'm delaying 1 second

```
exten => n,Dial (SIP/97,60,D(ww1234))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using macros

```
[macro-send]
exten => s,1,SendDTMF(*11234*,200)
exten => s,n,Wait(3)
exten => s,n,SendDTMF(#*)

[yourDialPlan]
exten => 224,1,NoOp(IN CALL : ${CALLERID(num)} => ${EXTEN})
exten => 224,n,Dial(${PJSIP_DIAL_CONTACTS(97,97)},,M(send))
exten => 224,n,Hangup()
```

Comment: Tried it, seems like it doesnt respond to the second command.

    -- Executing [224@from-internal:3] Dial("PJSIP/705-00001014", "PJSIP/97/sip:97@172.16.90.251:5060,M(send)") in new stack

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put a comma in Dial command there needs to be two commas between M(send) option and your variable exten => 224,n,Dial(${PJSIP_DIAL_CONTACTS(97,97)},,M(send)) @dermont